# IntelliJ IDEA 13.0 + TFS 2012

Tags: intellij-idea

When i try connect to TFS Server i have the error:

> org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement
>   RelativeToSetting.

Type Auth: Alternate, in tfs login i enable this option.

Has anyone encountered similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a little older but for future searchers.

This is currently a [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112210) logged in their issue tracker with no information on to when it may be fixed, or what versions of IntelliJ it will be fixed in.